# How to Pause Statements Execution and UIalertview Run On separate Loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, uialertview

Hi am working on Xmpop chat application , while file transfaring asking Permission For incomming File Acceptense . For this task am using like this.

```
UIAlertView *alrt = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Incommming File" message:name delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Reject" otherButtonTitles:@"Accept", nil];
    alrt.tag = 1111;
    [alrt show];
    while (buttonClicked == -1)
    {
        NSLog(@"-- runloop");
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2]];
    }
    if (buttonClicked == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~YES");
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~NO");
        return NO;
    }
```

This code Working in Sample Application but UI blocking In My Chat Application. How can i do this Please help Me.. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: can you share the link of the example?

Comment: Can you tell in which function this `while` loop is being called?

Comment: above statements all are belongs to '-(BOOL)incommingFileRequest:(XMPPIQ *)inIq' method shoud return Bool which  we selected,(Accept or Reject)

Comment: can you share the link of the example?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `[alrt show];` in an asynchronous block!

Something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) ^{
    [alrt show];
}
```

Hope this helps!